# How to save text with SharedPreferences dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a note application. I had an idea to save notes with shared preferences. Here's something I had in mind for saving new notes:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

for(int i=0;; i++) {
    pref = getSharedPreferences(i+1000, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    if(getString(i,null) == null) {
        editor.putString(i, "what i want to save");
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

If there's some method better than sharedPreferences or if there is a better way to do so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a note app, you should not use shared preferences to store your notes. You should store them in an SQLite database.

This method might not be *better*, but it's more suitable. For creating an SQLite database, see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Now suppose you have read through all that and is like, "Whaaaat... That's so complicated!"

I know, saving data into SQLite databases isn't easy. I would recommend you to use an external library to "enhance" your experience in using SQLite databases.

An example of this kind of libraries is [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/). You just need to create a class like this:

```
public class Note extends SugarRecord<Note> {
    public String noteString;
    public Note() {} // default constructor is required
    public Note(String string) {
        noteString = string;
    }
}
```

To save a note,

```
Note note = new Note("Sweeper is awesome.");
note.save();
```

To get all the notes,

```
List<Note> notes = Note.listAll(Note.class);
```

See what I mean? It's insanely easy!

Another one of these libraries is called [StorIO](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio). It provides similar stuff. It's *your* choice which one you use!

Comment: Thanks so much, i think i need to study more cuz i don't wanna spoil my app.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it! @mazhar

Comment: i get this error: cannot resolve SugarRecord. and it doesnt recommend any libraries to import! should i download sth?

Comment: Using a database just to save some notes seems a bit overkilling the target.

Comment: @mazhar did you read the get started guide on the website? You need to add the dependency to your gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it won't matter how you save your data, as you are only saving small amounts.

If you are using SharedPreferences, consider the follwoing:

- SharedPrefernces are intended for **key-value-pairs**. If your data doesn't consist of pairs, but e.g. a list, consider using a file to save.
- **Never save huge amounts** of data **to SharedPreferences**. This will increase your apps start time and memory footprint.

Alternatives to Sharedpreferences are files or databases.

Looking specifically at your code: You are creating new sharedprefences for each note! This will increase your apps storage usage, you'd better avoid it.

### Recommended Solution for your usecase

Use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to write your List of notes to a file. (This should work for any other datastructure too).

Serialization example:

```
String[] notes = [your notes]
Writer writer = new FileWriter("Output.json");
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(notes, writer);
```

Deserialization example:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("Output.json");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] notes = gson.fromJson(reader, String[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your information :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many attributes and details about a note you are storing. I would recommend an SQLite database for this. For start, you can have a look at [Simple notes](https://github.com/rnikolaus/Notes/tree/master/src/rnikolaus/notes) project on Github that uses [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class to manage database.

Comment: Sure thanks ill consider it :)